# How to order by json property of Posgres in Spring boot JPA?

Tags: postgresql, spring-boot, spring-data-jpa

I wrote a `@Query` in `JPA` to fetch the details by `json` property which is resulting error.

```
 @Query("SELECT t FROM Tcl order by t.equipment->>'eqpm_n' ASC")
 public List<Tcl> getEquipmentList();
```

Caused by: org.hibernate.hql.internal.ast.QuerySyntaxException: unexpected token

```
 SELECT t FROM com.target.mpe.models.Tcl order by t.equipment->>'eqpm_n' ASC
```

And same query is working well in Postgres console. 
How can i make it work in SpringBoot JPA?
Do i need to try Native Query?

Comment: Maybe it gets confused by that package name. Try `SELECT *`  just for testing purposes.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

JPQL does not support this PostgreSQL syntax. You have to use a nativeQuery:

```
@Query(value = "SELECT * FROM Tcl t order by t.equipment->>'eqpm_n' ASC", nativeQuery = true)
public List<Tcl> getEquipmentList();
```

Comment: Thanx for your help.